# Convert Samba Active Directory to sssd instead of winbind

Tags: active-directory, samba4, ubuntu-18.04, sssd, winbind

I've inherited a `Samba 4 Active Directory` (AD) server. It works fine with `winbind`, however for security reasons we'd like to change to `sssd`. The domain has two domain controllers (primary and secondary) both online.

I've created a test client machine, and followed the steps [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html.en) to connect to the domain using `sssd`. The client says it has connected to the domain, and ***does*** appear in the domain (When I use `Active directory users and computers`.)

However, logins and `getent` do not work.

**/var/log/auth.log**

```
Jun 12 14:19:16 clientCompName sshd[9349]: Invalid user adusername from xxx.xxx.xx8.149 port 42304
Jun 12 14:19:20 clientCompName sshd[9349]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jun 12 14:19:20 clientCompName sshd[9349]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xx8.149
Jun 12 14:19:21 clientCompName sshd[9349]: Failed password for invalid user adusername from xxx.xxx.xx8.149 port 42304 ssh2
```

If I do a `realm discover`, I notice the clients seem to be locked into using `winbind`.

```
root@clientCompName:/etc/pam.d# realm discover ADDOMAIN.MYDOMAN.DE
addomain.mydomain.de
type: kerberos
realm-name: ADDOMAIN.MYDOMAN.DE
domain-name: addomain.mydomain.de
configured: kerberos-member
server-software: active-directory
client-software: winbind
required-package: winbind
required-package: libpam-winbind
required-package: samba-common-bin
login-formats: SMBAD\%U
login-policy: allow-any-login
```

***/etc/pam.d/common-auth***

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_sss.so use_first_pass
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

***/etc/pam.d/common-session***

```
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
session required                        pam_permit.so
session optional                        pam_umask.so
session required        pam_unix.so 
session optional                        pam_sss.so 
session optional        pam_systemd.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

***/etc/pam.d/common-account***

```
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so 
account requisite                       pam_deny.so
account required                        pam_permit.so
account sufficient                      pam_localuser.so 
account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore]    pam_sss.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

**Is there a way to convert the AD to use `sssd` instead of `winbind` (or to accept both?)**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - you can exclude the samba packages if you like?

```
yum install sssd krb5­workstation samba­common authconfig adcli krb5-workstation samba samba-client sssd-libwbclient policycoreutils-python 
systemctl enable sssd
systemctl start sssd
systemctl enable smb
systemctl restart smb
authconfig --update --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enablemkhomedir
```

edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` lines to look like…

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
```

Then

```
kinit adminuser
```

(use an AD admin account)

```
klist
```

(check ticket)

```
realm join --user=\adminuser@DOMAIN DOMAIN
```

Edit `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
```

Then:

```
systemctl start sssd
```

Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` & check lines still there :

```
security = ads
realm = DOMAIN 
workgroup = ...
```

Then:

```
systemctl restart smb
```

Test:

```
realm discover DOMAIN
id domainuser
```